# OpenMP nesting not turning off

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I'm trying to manage nested parallel regions with OpenMP (4.5, via GCC 7.2.0) and I'm having some issues turning off nesting.

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void foobar() {
  int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int otid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("%d | %d\n", tid, otid);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  omp_set_nested(0);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    foobar();
  }
  printf("\n");
  foobar();
  return 0;
}
```

What I'm *expecting* to happen here is both the parallel region and non-parallel call on foobar() will spit out 4 lines, something to the tune of

```
// parallel region foobar()
0 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
// serial region foobar()
0 | 0
0 | 1
0 | 2
0 | 3
```

As I am not allowing nested parallelism.  However, I get 16 lines within the parallel region with the correct TID, but the OTID is always 0 (i.e. every thread is spawning 4 of its own, and executing the entire loop on that) and I get 4 lines outside (i.e. the parallel for is spawning 4 threads as I would expect)

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, can anybody shed some light for me?  Isn't disabling nesting supposed to turn that omp parallel for into a regular omp for, and distribute the work accordingly?

Comment: Rather than describing the output you're getting, [edit] the question to include the actual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from the false assumption that the `omp for` directive will be interpreted and the corresponding work distributed among the threads irrespective of which `parallel` region is active. Unfortunately, in your code, the `omp for` is only associated with the `parallel` region that is declared in function `foobar()`. Therefore, when this region is activated (meaning since you disabled the nested parallelism, when `foobar()` isn't called from another `parallel` region) your loop will be distributed among the newly spawn threads. But when it isn't, because `foobar()` is called from another `parallel` region, then the `omp for` is ignored and the loop isn't distributed among the calling threads. So each and every one of them executes the whole loop, leading to the replication of `printf()` that you see.

A possible solution would be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void bar(int tid) {
  #pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int otid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("%d | %d\n", tid, otid);
  }
}

void foobar() {
  int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  int in_parallel = omp_in_parallel();
  if (!in_parallel) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    bar(tid);
  }
  else {
    bar(tid);
  }
}

int main() {
  #pragma omp parallel
  foobar();
  printf("\n");
  foobar();
  return 0;
}
```

I don't really find this solution entirely satisfying, but I don't see any better one right now. Maybe later will I get some enlightenment...

**EDIT:** well I had another idea: doing it the other way around and forcing the nested parallelism, with only one single active thread whenever the function was called from an actual `parallel` region:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void foobar() {
  int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  omp_set_nested(1);
  #pragma omp single
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int otid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("%d | %d\n", tid, otid);
  }
}

int main() {
  #pragma omp parallel
  foobar();
  printf("\n");
  foobar();
  return 0;
}
```

And this time the code looks much nicer without any duplication, and gives (for example):

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./nested
3 | 2
3 | 3
3 | 1
3 | 0

0 | 3
0 | 1
0 | 0
0 | 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately those solutions don't work in my actual use case.  That does clear up what was happening, however.  I suppose I misunderstood how the dynamic scoping of parallel regions behaved.